# Pandas CSV delimiter, special character and insert inside a row question

Tags: python, pandas, csv

sorry for asking 2 times but my teacher said i can use pandas now.
Finish output

[files](https://github.com/emanuelOchoa/csv)

[What they want(pic of the solution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID7cK.png)

[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkxPA.png)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Programacion/1.csv',sep=";", encoding='latin1')
new_column = pd.DataFrame({'Movimientos': ['S', 'E', 'S']})
df = df.merge(new_column, left_index = True, right_index = True)
df.to_csv('C:/Programacion/aaaaaa.csv', index = False)
```

- I have problems with the special characters like º
- Some columns and rows are together, but i have the delimiter ';' so i dont know why this is happening
- I'm trying to insert every day the value 10:00 and 10:15 inside "Horas". Like the pic of the solution

Comment: could you please include the source data (and hopefully the desired output, too) as *text* (not a screenshot) in the question?

Comment: ok, post edited https://github.com/emanuelOchoa/csv

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the files you uploaded to github as an encoding issue, but nevertheless - here's a way to read it:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelOchoa/csv/master/source.csv"

res = requests.get(url)
content = res.content.decode('utf-8','ignore')

pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep = ";")
```

The result:

[image]